# Get Culture and UICulture by JQuery

Tags: jquery, cultureinfo

I am wondring if it is possible to get Culture and UICulture of the client form Javascript.

Thanks

Comment: I have also this question, should any one tell me that how can I get culture in Jquery or javascript

Answer (score 1):

There is No Way to do That directly by using Jquery, however if you are using .NET framework you can set Culture and UICulture in public properties and read them from Jquery.

in your CS file:

```
public string GetCurrentCulture
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName;
            }
        }
```

And from HTML:

```
var CurrentCulture = '';
$(document).ready(function () {
    CurrentCulture = '<%= this.GetCurrentCulture %>';
});
```